# Does Oracle BI Publisher support XMP metadata in PDF

Tags: pdf, siebel, xmp, bi-publisher

I would like to know if Oracle BI Publisher supports XMP metadata in the PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the doc's [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e22259/javaapis.htm#BIPDV578).

The section on PDF form processing; "The PDF Form Processing Engine creates a PDF document by merging a PDF template with an XML data file. This can be done using file names, streams, or an XML data string." It then gives some examples.